# dynamically generate map area coords from clicks over an image (jquery or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dictionary, coordinates

I wondered if there is a way to generate map area coords dynamically by clicking certain parts of an image. This is in order to generate a full image map.

As an example, I have this image:

[View image by clicking here...](http://mauricio.lairet.es/_otr/plano.jpg)

and by clicking on it, I want to generate coordinates for each defined area, outputing something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="36" value="25,11,25,117,47,117,46,29,83,31,84,8" />
<input type="text" name="37" value="83,12,103,32" />
```

etc...

Then I will save this on database for later use and processing.

I want to do something similar to what this website does, but more simple. I just need to maintain the functionality of displaying of the lines while drawing for the user to see what he is doing, and, off course, retrieve the coords.

[Online Image Map Editor](http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap)

Is there any jquery plugin that already does this job or how can I accomplish this by using jquery or javascript.

Thank you in adavnce

Comment: Have you found any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the ImageMapster jQuery plugin:
http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html

Answer (score 2):

We had the same requirements. And we ended up using this jQuery plugin: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Hope it helps.